# how to list a repeater sub fields with label and value in Advanced Custom Field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've searched and I could not find any solution to list a repeater field rows with Label of sub field and its value.

in my case I want to list a repeater field sub fields with Label and value.
for example  :

'Sub Field Label' = 'Value'

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2 and https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#group

Comment: @RichardMiles it's not advanced custom field plugin...

Any suggestion with advanced custom field plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the labels you want to retrieve from your [Repeater Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/), just use the standard method:

```
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
    while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
        echo 'Label = ' . get_sub_field('sub_field_name') . '<br>';
    endwhile;
endif;
```

If you aren't in a single post/page or outside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), just add the `$post_id` as the second parameter to your ACF function calls. For example: `have_rows('repeater_field_name', $post_id)`.

---

If you don't know the label names, I guess you could use `get_fields()` to get an array of all custom fields for the current post and iterate it. Something like:

```
$fields = get_fields($post->ID);
foreach ($fields as $field_type => $field) {
    if ( $field_type == 'repeater_field' ) {
        foreach ($field as $row) {
            foreach ($row as $label => $value) {
                // In this case you should be aware that
                // $value could be an Array too...
                echo $label . ' = ' . $value;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, I recommend you to take a look at [ACF Documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/). It's complete, clear and with lots of code snippets covering the most common uses.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'post');
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            query_posts( $args );
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $field = get_field_object('field_name'); 
   echo $field['label']; //print label name
   echo the_field('field_name'); //and its value
    endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

please try this hope help to you

Comment: you are welcome! if you accept answer then tick upper arrow..help other someone